# Certain network causes staging Dataflow template to be stuck at `Refreshing Access Token`

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

When I start staging Dataflow template, if I use my home's Wifi, the process would be stuck and repeat the following messages:

```
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
```

However, if I use my phone's hotspot, the process works normally and the template is uploaded. Restarting both my computer and my router does not work.

The template is written in Python and apache-beam version is 2.17.0. My system is 64-bit Ubuntu GNOME 19.10 minimally installed, and the home network uses mesh Wifi, if it matters.

Comment: Please try logging in using 'gcloud auth login' to reauthenticate. More here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login

Comment: Interestingly, the terminal does not register that I have logged in on the browser. However, staging Dataflow is done through `python3 deploy.py` so it should not be related to `gcloud` in the first place, and above scenario happened even before I installed `gcloud`.

Comment: I see. Do you get any error while submitting over wifi? The logs you mentioned are info logs so shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: No, there were only unrelated `BeamDeprecatedWarning`. I have checked the logging level.

Comment: Can you share the command that you are using to launch the job. Also, terminal does require authentication even if you use deploy.py So please authenticate/re-authenticate the terminal and try again.